# How to create featured news in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I would like to have something like "featured news" which is just selection of news which are to be published on the main page. Is there an simple way to do this in TYPO3?

I was thinking of creating a new category "Featured news", and when creating the article, you would assign it to its category and also to this category. But this is very clumsy - due to [this bug](http://bugs.typo3.org/view.php?id=18365) you cannot do it directly and must first add the news with only one category, then edit it and add another.

**I guess there must be some more correct solution for featured instead of hacking the categories?**

Comment: the more elegant solution is to fix that bug, instead doing some workarounds.

Comment: Hi @mahotlz, I new to typo3, so I don't know what is clean solution to this and what is a workaroud. I rather considered creating a new category "Featured news" a workaround... and I asked because I expect there is some completely different, "clean" solution.... (?)

Comment: Another option is to move to `news` which has this feature build in (top news).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using categories is the best way of doing it. To add more categories, just save it and continue editing.

Another option would be to create an extension that add this functionality to tt_news, but it could be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put news in separate folder and set the list to display the news only from it.

BTW, don't use old bugtracker, the issue is moved to forge: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/23789

Comment: thank you Marcus. 1) with "folder" you probably mean page in the page list? Please be exact in terminology, I'm a beginner and get confused easily :) 2)  you have probably linked different bug? (might be related, but what about the original one)

Comment: Well, but the problem with pages maybe is that you cannot easily move between them nor add the news to more than one page...

Comment: 1) yes folder (or `sysfolder`) is a page which type is sysfolder, it's container for records and is not displayed in the frontend (FE). It has a icon of grey ... folder :) on the page tree. You can also put news records into common page, but using sysfolder you'll just be able to find it faster. 2) well the bug's commiter wrote that's probably the same bug. keep in mind that old bugtracker is depreciated